# Enable submit button if value greater or equal to the specified value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to enable the submit button in the form only if the second text value is equal or greater than the first text box value. I have checked for the solution before posting. I don't know what I am missing. Please help me regarding the same.

I have added the JSfiddle code on which I worked changing

**Form Code**

```
<form method="post" action="order.php">
    First Number
    <input type="text" id="total1" />
    <br>
    Second Number
    <input type="text" id="total2" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled title="Not Relevant">
</form>
```

**Script**

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#total1').val() >= ('#total2').val())
        $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}, 1);
```

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh2587/6xzgof5a/#&togetherjs=aADxs93xqs)

Comment: Use [edit] link to add jsfiddle  to question.

Comment: you are missing a`$`.. `('#total2').val()`

Comment: Thanks! I added '$' but still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `setInterval` to check the values. This will block the thread from doing anything else because you are basically creating an infinite loop.

You only need to know compare the values when you submit. Then either submit or prevent the submit from happening with [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```
let $form = $('form');
let $total1 = $('#total1');
let $total2 = $('#total2');

$form.on('submit', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($total1.val());
  let val2 = Number($total2.val());
  if (val1 < val2) { // If condition is NOT met.
    event.preventDefault(); // Default submit from happening.
    return false; // Stop function.
  }
});
```

Additionally you can listen for the `change` event on the form when a value in one of the inputs has changed and check the values there. Then based on the evaluation set the disabled property in the input button.

```
let $submitButton = $(':submit');

$form.on('input', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($total1.val());
  let val2 = Number($total2.val());
  let isDisabled = val1 < val2; // Will return true or false.
  $submitButton.prop('disabled', isDisabled);
});
```

If you want to compare numbers then change the input type to `number`. Otherwise you will be comparing strings.

```
<input type="number" id="total1" />
<input type="number" id="total2" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the text to number and run the code, but the submit button is disabled only its not getting enable if the condition is true too.

Comment: If Possible from your end can you please share me the JSFiddle Code Link

Comment: jQueries `.val()` method seems to always return a string. So you need to convert it to a `Number` first before comparing. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t549yr7d/) you requested. Oh, and make sure you've included jQuery.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, your code worked properly but can you have a look into the JSFiddle file, I need something which perform like this. [ https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh2587/0uhkx456/ ]

Comment: Well, just look at the code I've written for you, especially the `change` event part. Just extend that with your own code. And why have you stopped writing jQuery?

Comment: Hi, I tried writing some code the addition is working but now disable submit button is creating problem. Can you please have a look. [ https://jsfiddle.net/ritesh2587/nzu7v1Lf/26/ ]

Comment: Create a new question for this issue. And please explain what you are trying to do and what you expect it do to. I don't know what *is creating problem* means.