# Php string value to input number bypass error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to compare two input values when type is number and need get the value from a string? and why type=number can't parse values from php strings?

> Error: The specified value "'.$total2.'" cannot be parsed, or is
> out of range.

I found this code at this amazing answer: [Enable submit button if value greater or equal to the specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990717/enable-submit-button-if-value-greater-or-equal-to-the-specified-value)

But in this example the input get value from input.
For something reason the type=number can't handle correctly when an value stored as string is specified.

There is the code ready to copy and paste:

```
<?php
$total2 = "50"; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

      <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
let $form = $('form');
let $total1 = $('#total1');
let $total2 = $('#total2');
let $submitButton = $(':submit');

$form.on('submit', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($total1.val());
  let val2 = Number($total2.val());
  if (val1 < val2) { // If condition is NOT met.
    event.preventDefault(); // Default submit from happening.
    return false; // Stop function.
  }
});

$form.on('input', function(event) {
  let val1 = Number($total1.val());
  let val2 = Number($total2.val());
  console.log(val1, val2)
  let isDisabled = val1 < val2; // Will return true or false.
  $submitButton.prop('disabled', isDisabled);
});
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="order.php">
  <label for="total1">First Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total1" value="0" />
  <br>
  <label for="total2">Second Number</label>
  <input type="number" id="total2" value="'.$total2.'" hidden />
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" disabled title="Not Relevant">
    </form>  
<?php echo $total2;?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can print string $total2 echo successfully.
How to bypass this?

Any hint is welcome
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP opening/closing tags are missing from the HTML input.

```php
<input type="number" id="total2" value="'.$total2.'" hidden />
// should be
<input type="number" id="total2" value="<?php echo $total2; ?>" hidden />
```

If you don't use the opening/closing tags, PHP won't know that it should treat the `$total2` code as PHP code.